# How to use a variable in a .value() contstruct?

Tags: angularjs

I've got a bunch of global values that I'm defining in a `.value()` construct. I'd like to be able to define a variable in that, so that I can reference the variable rather than repeat the information over and over again, similar to:

```
.value('globalValues',
{
    host: "http://10.0.2.2/",
    site: "MySite/",

    adsApi: host + site + 'api/AdsApi/',
    accountApi: host + site + 'api/AccountApi/',
    accountLogout: host + site + 'Account/LogoutApi/'
})
```

Currently this doesn't work because `host` is undefined, and I'm unable to define `host` in that construct. Is this possible some other way?

Comment: Since you need variables...use a service instead

Comment: Angulars module handling is messy. You can change to standard js modules at least partially, and won't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` service is [syntactic sugar over `factory` service](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/auto/injector.js#L723) (and `factory` is sugared `provider` service).

```
app.value('globalValues', { ... });
```

is identical to

```
app.factory('globalValues', (() => {
  var eagerlyAssignedObj = { ... };

  return () => eagerlyAssignedObj;
})());
```

`factory` is the use case for an object that can't be defined at service definition time. Usually this means that additional data should be injected as another service:

```
app.factory('globalValues', (hostAndSiteService) => ({
  host: hostAndSiteService.host,
  ...
}));
```